# Issue between number of classes and shape of inputs in metric collection torch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have a problem because I want to calculate some metrics in torchmetrics. but there is a problem:

```
ValueError: The implied number of classes (from shape of inputs) does not match num_classes.
```

The output is from UNet and the loss function is BCEWithLogitsLoss (binary segmentation)

channels = 1 because of grayscale img

Input shape: (batch_size, channels, h, w) torch.float32

Label shape: (batch_size, channels, h, w) torch.float32 for BCE

Output shape: (batch_size, channels, h, w): torch.float32

```
inputs, labels = batch
outputs = model(input)
loss = self.loss_function(outputs, labels)
prec = torchmetrics.Precision(num_classes=1)(outputs, labels.type(torch.int32)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `torchmetrics` expects different shape. Try to flatten both output and labels:

```
prec = torchmetrics.Precision(num_classes=1)(outputs.view(-1), labels.type(torch.int32).view(-1))
```

Comment: Will it give the same result, sense as without flattening?

Comment: It should be the same because TP and FP values are the same for any order of pixels

Answer (score 1):

I was using the [torchmetrics](https://torchmetrics.readthedocs.io/en/stable/classification/f1_score.html#:%7E:text=F1%20metrics%20correspond%20to%20a%20equally%20weighted%20average%20of%20the,multi%2Ddimensional%20preds%20and%20target.) library for calculating F1 score, Precision and Recall for segmentation task; I was trying to get F1 score for both of my individual classes when I encountered the above error, this solution works but first of all I had to set '`multi_class=True`' with '`num_classes=2`'

```
torchmetrics_f1_none = torchmetrics.classification.F1Score(average=None, num_classes=2, multiclass=True) 

f1_0, f1_1 = torchmetrics_f1_none(thres_out.view(-1), masks.int().view(-1)) 

print("F1 Score for Background - {}, F1 Score for Foreground - {} \n".format(f1_0, f1_1))
```